# StencilJS unit testing keyboard event?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, event-handling, stenciljs

I want to write unit tests for my custom web-components in stencilJs but have no idea how to do it the right way. Here's what I did so far!

.tsx

```
...

  valueFormat(event: Event): void {
    const val = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const format = Number.parseInt(val, 10);
    const newVal = format.toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    });
    this.value = newVal;
  }
```

.spec.tsx

```
it('should format value', async () => {
    const comp = new MyComponent();
    const spy = jest.spyOn(comp, 'valueFormat');

    comp.myInputEvent.emit();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I want to test the case, when I type a number in the input field that it format it. So my valueFormat() method, I spying on should be called when a Keyboard event is firing. I hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test it with Event in mind, I would strongly recommend you to use newSpecPage(https://stenciljs.com/docs/unit-testing) - as this will allow you to construct your component DOM in memory and allow you to test its logic (so you can easily trigger event like click, keyboard or trigger input value change which I assume where your valueFormat() method get called/binded?)

Another approach is to move formatting logic to separate function which takes just input value as an argument like:

```
formatInputValue(value: string) {
  const format = Number.parseInt(value, 10);
  const newVal = format.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  });
  return newVal;
}
```

then you could easily unit test this method by simply constructing component and then calling the method with whatever the value you want to test with (this is useful if you want to test edge cases like null, empty value, non numeric value etc.)

Personally I wouldn't bother creating function as conversion logic seem to be simple - also one advantage of doing testing via DOM (using newSpecPage()) is that if you ever want to change your formatting logic, amount of test code you need to update could be quite small, meaning your test code is bit more maintainable (again just my personal opinion, it's all depends on how complex the formatting logic or the expected input be)